# Count if a table meets one or multiple conditions SQL

Tags: sql, count, case

I have two tables

Table

```
AnimalID | Date
```

Table2

```
AnimalID | ConditionID
```

`AnimalID` is the primary key of Table and includes the animals birthdate.

Table 2 has the `AnimalID` and any sickness `ConditionID` the animal has had. As a result `AnimalID` can occur in Table2 multiple times. I want to know about conditions 79, 80, 1000 and 90.

```
SELECT        DATEPART(year, Table.Date) AS x_Year,
                COUNT(Distinct Table.AnimalID) AS N_Killed,
                COUNT(CASE WHEN Table2.ConditionId =79 THEN 1 END) AS Col1,
                COUNT(CASE WHEN Table2.ConditionId =80 THEN 1 END) AS Col2,
                COUNT(CASE WHEN Table2.ConditionId =1000 THEN 1 END) AS Col3,
                COUNT(CASE WHEN Table2.ConditionId =90 THEN 1 END) AS Col4
FROM            Table LEFT JOIN
                         Table2 ON Table.AnimalID = Table2.AnimalID

GROUP BY DATEPART(year, Date)
ORDER BY DATEPART(year, Date)
```

But sometimes the animals have multiple conditions so I would like an additional column which shows if the number of animals which has had any of the conditions

Comment: Is the combination of AnimalID, ConditionID in Table2 unique?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would expect you to use `distinct` in all the aggregations since you would not want to count the same animal twice. To get a count of animals with any of those conditions, just use `in`

```
select datepart(year, a.date) as x_year,
       count(distinct a.animalid) as n_killed,
       count(distinct case when b.conditionid = 79 then a.animalid end) as col1,
       count(distinct case when b.conditionid = 80 then a.animalid end) as col2,
       count(distinct case when b.conditionid = 1000 then a.animalid end) as col3,
       count(distinct case when b.conditionid = 90 then a.animalid end) as col4,
       count(distinct case when b.conditionid in ('79','80','1000',90') then a.animalid end) as col5
from  table a 
left join table2 b on a.animalid = b.animalid
group by datepart(year, a.date)
order by datepart(year, a.date);
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically what you want to do is the same as you done with N_Killed, but only when there is a sickness to the animal.
Col4 just types the AnimalID there is a Condition, so by counting the unique AnimalId by using distinct you get the information you ask for.

```
SELECT        DATEPART(year, Table.Date) AS x_Year,
                COUNT(Distinct Table.AnimalID) AS N_Killed,
                COUNT(CASE WHEN Table2.ConditionId =79 THEN 1 END) AS Col1,
                COUNT(CASE WHEN Table2.ConditionId =80 THEN 1 END) AS Col2,
                COUNT(CASE WHEN Table2.ConditionId =1000 THEN 1 END) AS Col3,
                COUNT(Distnict CASE WHEN Table2.ConditionId is not null THEN Table.AnimalID END) AS Col4,
FROM            Table LEFT JOIN
                         Table2 ON Table.AnimalID = Table2.AnimalID

GROUP BY DATEPART(year, Date)
ORDER BY DATEPART(year, Date)
```